# Multimatch join in pandas

Tags: pandas, merge

I am looking for joining two data frame on one column and if there is a multi match then append the results to another column.

[image: First Dataframe]

[image: 2nd data frame]

[image: Expected Output from the Dataframe]

Comment: please provide your input data as text (not as image). What have you tried so far? Did you already write some code?

Answer (score 0):

*NB. using a different example as yours is not reproducible.*

You can convert to `str.lower`, then `explode` and `map` the values to `groupby.agg` again as string:

```
mapper = df2.set_index('name')['ID'].astype(str)
df1['ID'] = (df1['name']
             .str.upper().str.split(',')
             .explode()
             .map(mapper)
             .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
            )
```

Or, with a list comprehension:

```
mapper = df2.set_index('name')['ID'].astype(str)
df1['ID'] = [','.join([mapper[x] for x in s.split(',') if x in mapper])
             for s in df1['name']]
```

output:

```
  name   ID
0    A    1
1    b    2
2  A,B  1,2
3  C,a  3,1
4    D    4
```

Used input:

```
# df1
  name
0    A
1    b
2  A,B
3  C,a
4    D

# df2
  name  ID
0    A   1
1    B   2
2    C   3
3    D   4
```